# Printing only starts after last page spools

Tags: vb.net, printing, spool

I'm having a problem that printing in VB.net where any network printer I choose is waiting until the last page is spooled before printing begins. However I'm looking to have it begin printing after the first page. 
The printer is set to 'Start printing immediately', and this is giving me huge problems as we're trying to print duplex documents that may be 75 ~ 100 pages long.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's set to RAW in the Properties you are fine.  That's a queue level setting.  Why is this such an issue.  Does your print file take a really long time to create?

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste a little sample of the code you are using to print?  First off, I would look at the queue itself and ensure that things like the Print Processor are set to RAW and also confirm that other applications such as Word have no issue 'starting immediately' to this device.

Why is this such a big deal?  Does you application take a long time to generate the data that this causes issue?  You should be able to generate the print output quickly (assuming it's not a bunch of high res images or something) and get it into the queue fast.  Assuming you have an up to date printer that's doing 30-40ppm the entire process should only take a couple of minutes.

Comment: How do i select RAW from inside VB.net, it appears as if the data types in the printer properties are set to RAW, but they're only defaults arn't they? - Any way of overriding in .Net 2.0 (i have no access the the .Net 3 printqueue class)